# Allocating a single object larger than 2GB using new in C++ (on Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I am on Windows, x64 mode. Compiled using MSVC on Visual Studio. The `new` operator seems not to be working as intended when I do this:

```cpp
char* buf = new char[1LLU << 32];
```

But if I pass in a variable instead of directly typing the size, it works without a problem:

```cpp
uint64_t sz = 1LLU << 32;
char* buf = new char[sz];
```

Looking at the assembly code, the compiler ignored the size I provided and simply `xor ecx, ecx` which I believe is just passing 0 to the `new` operator.

This is really puzzling! Is there some rule specified in the standard that I am not aware of?

p.s. `char* buf = new char[1LLU << 31];` works without a problem. So I think its about the size of the integer I am using. But in documentation, `new` takes in a `size_t` as argument, which on x64 should be `uint64_t`.

**`VirtualAlloc()`/`HeapAlloc()` are good alternatives that are safer to use than `new` in this context.**

**Full Code (note* try reproduce this locally in Visual Studio):**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    char* ptr = new char[1LLU << 32];
    memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(char) * (1LLU << 32)); //Access violation writing location...
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    uint64_t sz = 1LLU << 32;
    char* ptr = new char[sz];
    memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(char) * (1LLU << 32)); //no problem
}
```

Comment: On Windows, if you do ```1 << 32```, it will overflow. If you want to set an integer larger than 32 bit, you have to do ```1LLU << 32```. By the way, this is the actual code. Works with ```1LLU << 31```, but not ```1LLU << 32``` (on this particular case)

Comment: Looking at [this example that doesn't do that](https://godbolt.org/z/nqTTtq), I'm guessing that there's something odd going on and you need to post a [mcve].

Comment: @OrientalSiru What does "_The `new` operator seems not working as intended when I do this:_" mean? Does not work as intended.. How?

Comment: @KenWhite U absolutely means unsigned  `1U<<x` is a common bitmask method.

Comment: `LL` and `U` are valid suffixes, if both are provided they may appear in any order.

Comment: @KenWhite `char unsigned` and `int unsigned` are fine. So is `LLU`.

Comment: @Ayxan: Strange. I've never seen them used that way. Thanks.

Comment: @molbdnilo Well, the assembly code generated from the link you posted is correct. But not on my computer. I am using the most recent windows SDK (10.0.18362.0) and toolset (v142).

Comment: @engf-010 I am certain that I am compiling it in x64 mode. I am not sure why it works fine here, but not locally using Visual Studio.

Comment: @engf-010 Hmm, I just tried on another computer. Same issue. Also I am 100% certain is in x64 mode. If you have access to Visual Studio, maybe you can try it. It seems "@bloody" is able to reproduce it locally.

Comment: @engf-010 But it works with ```uint64_t sz = 1LLU << 32; char* buf = new char[sz];```. Shouldn't be the case if I am on x86.

Comment: @engf-010 edited to include the full code.

Comment: You forgot to `#include<cstring>`. Could you add that and `static_assert(sizeof(std::size_t) == 64/8, "This should not be shown!");` at the beginning of main and the output of `std::cout << _MSC_VER << "\n";` might also be helpful to verify what and how you are compiling.

Comment: bug reported: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/779749/msvc-2019-erroneously-replaces-known-arraysize-gre.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `const` to your declaration:

```
const uint64_t sz = 1LLU << 32;
```

and you'll get the same error:

[Compiler Error C2148](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2148?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019)

This is a 'safety' MSVC threshold for an array allocation, but since you give non-const size variable the compiler does not resolve it at compile-time.

Comment: Interesting, that suggests that std::vector will suffer the same limitations.  Good to know.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I am curious why this is the case. Plus, this didn't throw any compiler error. Only when I call ```memset(buf, ...)``` it throws write access violation.

Comment: In fact, it just silently replaced my size with 0...without informing me

Comment: @OrientalSiru Hmm, perhaps it's a warning/error level settings?

Comment: that article is about compile time arrays (which don't fit the stack anyway).

Comment: @engf-010 For a record - the example is about a 'static' array. I'm getting the same error with `new` so apparently - not only.

Comment: Same here. Only weird part is that compiler doesn't throw any error.This particular one doesn't show up either when I turn on max level of warnings...hope Microsoft people can clarify it...

Comment: @Ukmonkey: Your vectors will work just like you expect them to.

Comment: I doubt this addresses the problem since it is talking about array types whereas the question regards dynamic allocation

Comment: @M.M. Read comment history more closely. I have already confirmed the error with `new` operator. Just an example shows a compile-time array. Regardless from the fact that OP observes yet different behavior (but I hadn't known that before his question was fully edited by engf-010). Anyway I believe both effects are somehow related.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely found a compiler bug (**targetting x64**) and you should submit it to microsoft.

It seems that whenever the compiler knows the actual size to allocate an array to be **greater_equal** than **2^33** it will wrongfully 'optimize' the size to **0**.
Since allocating a 0-size array is perfectly valid ,you'll get invalid access when accessing it beyond some index (the allocated array will occupy some memory).

bug reported: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/779749/msvc-2019-erroneously-replaces-known-arraysize-gre.html

BTW: std::array<> doesn't suffer from it ,it seems.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this on godbolt with the supposedly same version as OP (as far as I can tell that is msvc v19.20). So I am not so sure that one should jump to this being a bug so quickly.

Comment: @uneven_mark: my current version = Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.23.28106.4 for x64. So IMO it is a bug (as it stand now for VS2019). I don't know how to judge those godbolt versions.

Comment: Are you sure 2^33? Not 2^31 - 1 (`0x7fffffff` - the value which mentioned C2148 reports)? It seems like somehow related but wrongly handled...

Comment: @bloody: tested ,everything from (1ull << 32) and up fails ,below that is Ok. 0x7FFFFFFF is a restriction for 32bit programs so that one can do pointer arithmatic with signed integers and this restriction is unwanted for 64 bit programs (vs2017 incorrectly errors on it)

Comment: OK, so I finally understand why these are two separate issues. However both revealed only by compile-time resolution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's been a while but it's officially a bug and Microsoft are fixing it :-)

SO was right that it's a sign extension problem that has been lurking since the beginning of the x64 days.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cant-new-an-object-more-than-2GB-in-size/10328982#T-ND10337717